# Load and unload a page into a div from a page already loaded in

Tags: jquery, html, load

Im using this code:

```
<!--Page Loading Mechanism-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
            e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link


            $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) , function() {
            /* Content is now loaded */


        });
      });

   });
</script>
```

to load in external pages using a navigation menu in the parent page.  Ok, now it loads the pages fine when i click on the nav buttons.

Now, what im trying to do is load another external page into this same div from a button on the child page.  Im trying to basically overwrite the child with thew page.  I thought a regular `< a href>` would do the trick, but it does nothing but opens the new page into the main window, replacing the parent page. I dont want that.

How do I replace the first child page, with the new external page, but into the same div the child was already loaded, replacing it. What code would I write on the first loaded child page?

I pray you all are not confused reading this, as this is the best way i could explain it.

Comment: I am totally confused, but by: "Im trying to basically overwrite the child with thew page", have you thought of using ajax to fetch the contents of the page and set the responseHTML to the div?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you, of course if using ajax is OK..

```
$.ajax({url:"url",
        success : onSuccess
});

function onSuccess(result){
$("#<id of div to be updated>").html(result);
}
```

Comment: would i put this code on the first child page being loaded in?

Comment: call this when you want to load the contents into the div, say, if it is a button call on the 'click' event. like `$("#LoadExternalPageButton").click(function(){//here goes the code above})` .

Comment: @WillingLearner Exactly what part of the code doesnt work for you? Dont want to use ajax? Its not a button? Its not loading? Or just simply the code fails to do what its intended to? It will be better if you can share a sample of the code on fiddle or so, or atleast explain in more detail...

Comment: it loads the same way it was before i tried to use the code. No change. If you could create an example of your code working in action, it may work out better for me.